Who was the Rabbi of the Maso Moshe, Chacham Moshe Sawid?
I was working on an article trying to connect our generation's rabbis, specifically MaRan Chacham Ovadia, to his rabbi, Rabbi Ezra Atia, and him to his rabbi, Chacham Avraham Ades and so on until I got to Chacham Moshe Sawid (I saw websites writting it as Swed but the right hebrew pronunciation of סוויד seems more like sawid) where I got stuck. He was a giant talmid chacham and also was the chief rabbi of Aleppo (also known as Aram Tzova). He was the rabbi of many great chachamim of his generation.
I tried going around through one of his students whose rabbi was also the famed Rabbi Chaim Vital and then I moved on and on until I reached the age of rishonim.
Nevertheless, I didn't find the rabbi of Chacham Sawid. Very likely that he should be connected to the earlier mekubalim of the generation like as said above, Rabbi Chaim Vital, but I need something sourced and not just ideas.

So far, the closest I've found is that in Rabbi Suwid's eulogy of his father-in-law, he mentions "מורינו הרב הגדול מוהרש"ל" (our teacher, the great rabbi Moharshal) which is a reference to Rabbi Refael Shlomo Laniado, former chief rabbi of Aleppo. But it's not clear whether that's just a general honorific or if he actually considered him to be his direct rabbi. https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21877&st=&pgnum=138

I found few names in his responsa which he referred to as מו"ר, I am at doubt if it refers to מורינו ורבינו which is more general term or מורי ורבי. Thank you anyways.

Some of the names you found might perhaps be narrowed down if they did not live in his lifetime, or were more likely to have been friends/contemporaries/generational equals rather than his own teachers.

Good Idea, must check it.

No, it’s pronounced ”swed”. The article was correct in that regard.

see here: סֻׂוִויד https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%95%D7%99%D7%93#:~:text=%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91%20%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9F-,%D7%A1%D6%BB%D7%82%D7%95%D6%B4%D7%95%D7%99%D7%93,-(%3F%20%2D%20%D7%9B%22%D7%98%20%D7%91%D7%90%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%9E%22%D7%98
